# JavaScript JQuery String Var to show in a field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with JavaScript JQuery, and when i try to show the content of the vars in a field, it doesn't work.
There is my code:

```
function editEvolution(pos, nature, desc, di) {
      $('#diE').val(di);
      $('#natureE').val(nature);
      $('#descE').val(desc);

      $('#BtnAddEditEvo').attr('value', "Update");
      $('#BtnAddEditEvo').attr('onclick', "doEditEvolution("+pos+")");

}
```

Thank's in advance for help.

the value of fields `$('#diE')`, `$('#natureE')` and `$('#descE')` doesn't change if the vars nature, desc, are strings but it works if it is a number

Comment: Really? `.attr('onclick'`... REALLY?

Comment: it would help immensely if you have a jsfiddle for us to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing the worst from both the native JS, inline JS and jQuery worlds. You NEVER EVER put code inside a string, period. If you do it, you are doing it wrong.

So.. how to do it properly?

```
$('#BtnAddEditEvo').val('Update').on('click', function() {
    doEditEvolution(pos);
});
```

In case you call `editEvolution` multiple times on the same object, add `.off('click')` before the `.on(...)` call to unbind previous handlers.

Comment: i don't understand very well the solution, but the problem is always here because my problem isn't in the button but in showing the var values in the fields

Comment: What type of fields are they? `<input>`?

Comment: They are "text" inputs

Comment: Then using `.val()` should work assuming the IDs are correct and unique.

Comment: yes, with firebug i see that the values of vars are correct, and the very weird is when the inputs are numbers it works !

Comment: Because numbers do not need to be passed in quotes! Strings need to be passed in quotes! It is what my answer shows!

Answer (score 2):

First do not use attr to set onclick...

I will explain what is wrong

```
$('#BtnAddEditEvo').attr('onclick', "doEditEvolution("+pos+")");
```

if `pos="foo"`, it will render as

```
<div onclick="doEditEvolution(foo);"></div>
```

See the problem? It is looking for a variable `foo`. You would need to add quotes.

```
$('#BtnAddEditEvo').attr('onclick', "doEditEvolution('"+pos+"')");
                                                     ^       ^
```

Why does a number work? Because numbers do not need quotes. It makes a valid call. It renders as:

```
<div onclick="doEditEvolution(3);"></div>
```

What you need to do is use jQuery the right way and use events.

```
$('#BtnAddEditEvo').on('click', function() { doEditEvolution(pos); });
```

and you should set value with `.val()`

Comment: Btw, using quotes is also a bad idea since it would break in case of the string containing quotes. `JSON.stringify()` would be better. Not to mention that it would still be crap because of the whole "putting code in a string" part...

Comment: But yees im looking for the variable foo

Comment: Do you realize what you are doing is: `var myString = "asdf" + pos + "qwert";`  It is not a reference to the variable, it is a string....

Comment: yes i know what you mean, it's very useful thank you epascarello